# How to ensure that two rasters are using the same FID or that they are the same pixel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I am doing a Dasymetric analysis for my study area. It is through a toolbox for ArcMap.

It needs a base raster that has Landcover classification based on urban form and redistributes the population using that base landcover raster.

My Dasymetric raster for population is correct as the total population matches.
Now I need to recalculate the population for the corresponding urban form class.

I have converted them in polygons as I need to do further analysis.
So far good...

The problem is when I intersect the population/dasymetric shapefile with landcover shapefile, the corresponding values dont seem to match (for example, water bodies have zero population, which it does in both raster to polygon layers) but when I check the Excel table for the intersected file, it gives me population for water bodies as well.

To me, this looks like a mismatch between pixels. As in the pixels do not have same FID and hence the values dont correspond as it should have been.

I want to know if there is any process or tool to compare the difference or if there is a process where I can ensure that the FID for each pixel is same in both rasters.

I am not conversant with any other software or Python so I seek only tools/ options within ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: A "FID" is a feature ID. It isn't an actual field, just the record number in the shapefile. You should not *ever* do comparisons based on FID. ArcMap 10.4 has recently been Retired; 10.3 has been Retired for more than a year. There are of course multiple ways to be sure that your comparisons are correct, but by restricting the comparison to Excel, you make the task far more difficult.